# Cant get Google App to show on Google site

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I have 3 different google apps written to scroll through a set of images. i then have a master app that shows them in a iframe but there is a drop down at the top of the page to select which slide deck to view. Published and viewed as a separate app page it works great ([click here](https://script.google.com/a/macros/experis.co.uk/s/AKfycbxzGexl7YXS_GzVgvCfLF3QUBHPH9o_-PbbI4jJ_Wms9iConKI1/exec)) but when i embed it in to our Google site it shows the drop down menu but not the sliders, any ideas why this is?

its pretty basic in what the html is -

```html
  <header class="main-header">
    
    <ul class="main-nav">
      <li class="dropdown">Change KPI Report Type
        <ul class="drop-nav">
          <li><a href="//script.google.com/a/macros/experis.co.uk/s/AKfycbwfeWNXStsW2vxRgZ13uDZdoo1n_fjhMpTONm_u2yVv2k7Iasw/exec" target="myiframe">Start Date</a></li>
          <li class="last"><a href="//script.google.com/a/macros/experis.co.uk/s/AKfycbxXbZWWJlJo0u3PTiIsS3uWU-Yz6P80vQE2OG5PjHSXIH3LuJE/exec" target="myiframe">Placement Date</a></li>      
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  
  <body>
  
  <iframe src="//script.google.com/a/macros/experis.co.uk/s/AKfycbwfeWNXStsW2vxRgZ13uDZdoo1n_fjhMpTONm_u2yVv2k7Iasw/exec" name="myiframe" ></iframe>
```

Any ideas why this is?

Comment: i have tried this with 3 random images from google and it works on my google site so it is something to do with the scripts in the iframe

Comment: not clear where you are inserting that. Google sites use gadgets to insert apps script. other external sites cannot iframe a google apps script webapp

Comment: its on a Google Site using the app script insert gadget.

Comment: replace "script." with "sites." in the iframe url

Comment: you legend!! works perfectly now. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace "script." with "sites." in the iframe url. this will workarround some cross-origin browser restrictions.

unfortunately Google hasnt fixed this for years now.